# TableRowSorter and RowFilter - searching visible and rendered columns

Tags: java, jtable

I am using TableRowSorter and RowFilter for filtering data in a JTable. I have come across 2 issues while using it.

1) My table has visible and hidden columns. I would like to avoid searching hidden columns. Is there a way to do that?

2) I am using custom cell renderers to render the values in the cell. I would like to search the rendered value instead of the actual value. For example when actual value is "true" for status column, the rendered value is "enabled". I should be able to see data when search text is enabled.

Could you please help?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

1) Read the JTable API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Tables". The filter example shows how to filter on a specific column

2) I guess you would have to create a custom filter. Inside the filter you would need to invoke the prepareRenderer(...) method using the value in the TableModel. I've never done this so I'm can't give an example.